# Winform Application Keeps Using Wrong Connection String Data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have built a winform app that connects to an SQL database to retrieve data.
The connection string is stored in a class called ConnectionData. 
I have migrated the solution to another server machine for production however after creating and altering the database and connection string on the new environment it keeps referring to the connection string on the test environment.
I have altered the application to accept code that is different from the original source and used a number of solutions posted online but it keeps using the wrong connection string, unless I use. Breakpoint to alter the value by hand.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is that code the only place to get connection string? Perhaps the old connection string is still lurking around somewhere in configuration file or in code. You can search the entire solution with old database server name to find if it is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I'm positive its the only place the connection string still exists.

Comment: It will be tough for anyone to guess why this is happening as there could be multiple reasons for this. I would recommend searching for old connection strings, ensuring that you are in fact deploying the new code and replacing the old executable if names are different.

Comment: there is too much possibility to your question

Comment: do you have a log in place that would make it possible to see what the cause is/ where the code reads out information? Do you keep this information as a setting in app.config or is it hardcoded? Maybe some code would be pretty helpful